# "He sees her take..." or "He sees her takes..."?

Tags: grammaticality

> He sees Sophia hurriedly **take** a syringe  and **inject** it into Alex's forearm.

> He sees Sophia hurriedly **takes** a syringe and **injects** it into Alex's forearm.

Which one correct? Up to my knowledge, the first is correct and the second is wrong.

Comment: It would certainly be *take* and not *takes*, but as previously mentioned the sentence still doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction you are probably looking for is

> He sees Sophia hurriedly take a syringe (…).

Your other proposal, “he sees her takes …”, is definitely grammatically impossible, because the `-s` final on *takes* requires a third person subject, but the verb *takes* cannot have a subject here (the pronoun *her* cannot be a subject, it has to be *she*).

The general form is:

- a verb expressing perception (“sees”)
- a subject performing an action (“Sophia”)
- the action, with the verb in the [infinitive without “to”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Bare_infinitive) (“hurriedly take a syringe”)

The subject who performs the action is, grammatically speaking, a complement of the verb of perception. Therefore, if it is a pronoun, that pronoun is in the complement (sometimes called accusative) form, not in the subject (nominative) form.

> He sees her hurriedly take a syringe.

The meaning of this sentence is that he sees the action as a whole. It is also possible to use the [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English) instead of the infinitive, with a different meaning: the action is seen while it is ongoing.

> He sees her taking a syringe.

This means that he sees her while she is taking the syringe. He doesn't see the whole act, just a part of it. It is usually implied that he sees enough to identify the action: ”he sees her taking a syringe“ implies that from what he sees, he can tell that she is taking a syringe.

Another grammatically correct, but rarer sentence, is:

> He sees that she takes a syringe.

The context where this sentence can be correct is different though: the present simple indicates a habitual action. This sentence means that he sees something that allows him to deduce that she habitually takes a syringe (under certain circumstances that are implicit from the context).

The verb can also be in the present continuous:

> He sees that she is taking a syringe.

The meaning is close to “he sees her taking a syringe”, but the use of a separate clause makes it clear that from what he sees, he can conclude that she is taking a syringe. In fact, it is possible that he doesn't see the action itself, but he sees something that implies that she is taking a syringe.

All this could apply to any other verb of perception: *see*, *watch*, *hear*, *feel*, …

Comment: I edited my sentence. Sorry for wrong sentence I posted. The correct sentence is "He sees Sophia hurriedly take a syringe and punch into Alex's forearm."